# Make a wizard like application in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been developing an asp simple application with some form fields etc. I want to make it a wizard like application like when you type in some fields you can click next and a new section appears on the same form and finally using all the data collected from the forms I can perform my operations at the end.

Kindly can you link me to such tutorials for winforms

Comment: Be nice.  :-)  presumably this is a newer .NET developer.  We all started somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using this component, which I've used successfully in a few WinForms apps:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DesignTimeWizard.aspx

It comes with source code so that you can see what it's doing it, and how it's doing it.  You can learn from it and modify what you need to, or even just use it as-is.

There are other WinForms wizard projects at CodePriject.com, and I've seen a few articles, but in my limited experience, this is the best I've seen, with a free price point, and the source code available for you to work with.